# How do I install Maven on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, maven, environment-variables

Forgive my noobishness, after downloading and installing Maven, how do I configure the environment variable on windows 10? From Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables I can't relate with the interface. I don't know what to do now as I don't want to mess up my paths.

Comment: That's a list of directories in the path.  You want to add one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add Maven to Windows path you have to create a new variable `MAVEN_HOME=<MAVEN_PATH>` and then adding this variable to the `PATH/path` like `<PATH_PREVIOUS_VALUE>;%MAVEN_HOME%/bin;`

Answer (score 0):

Check http://sdkman.io/ !
They have a powershell version, awesome tool for are tools that work on JVM

Answer (score 0):

I was able to edit the path instead of picking on the list as windows 10 presents it. I just clicked on "Edit Text" and it brought out the window in the old fashioned way.